# She was LAST across the finish line.

Tags: grammar

Please help. What part of speech is "last" in the sentence:

She was last across the finish line.

Thank you!

Comment: Whether words like ***first, last*** are being used as adverbs or adjectives is often little more than a matter of opinion. Just as *"I heard her **singing**"* could be either a gerund/noun or a progressive tense usage, depending on how you intend to shoehorn actual language into your chosen categorisation system (where "you" as the speaker might take the opposite view to "you" as the audience, or a third-party "grammarian adjudicator", and it's meaningless to suggest one is right and the others wrong).

Answer (score 1):

It is an adjective. If you look up "last" in say [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/last) you will see that it is listed as an adjective. The definition also provides some good example sentences.

Comment: +1, though I find it odd you enjoined OP to look up *first* in the dictionary to find out that word's part of speech, rather than to simply look up *last* directly. Anyway, please pull up the definition of *last* in the dictionary of your choice quickly, and copy in the part of speech information (with attribution to that dictionary, of course!), so that OP and the others that follow behind him know they can trust your answer.

Comment: I'm confused because somone else I asked says it's an adverb. He says the sentence is the same as "She came last at the race" and that that makes it an adverb. I can't tell at all!

Answer (score 1):

This is a situation where a dictionary may well not help.

> She was last across the finish line.

is a reduced form of

*She was the last person across the finish line.*

So 'last' is standing in for the complete noun phrase *the last person*.

If any part of speech is considered necessary, a determiner acting as noun is a strong candidate.

Notice that

> He finished first

is ambiguous. The adverbial reading (ie 'first' as an adverb) means he finished temporally before everyone else did. But the reduced form of 'in first position' does not entail this (it could have been a time trial, and 34 riders finished their trials before the eventual winner).